# Android Studio 3.0 can't suggest import for shl and shr in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the import for shl and shr for android ?
I converted java file to Kotlin and all << and >> became shl and shr. But Android Studio says it cannot resolve it and doesn't suggest any import :(

Comment: sounds like a bug in Android Studio code such as `65536 shr 3` or `1 shr 7` should be understood without any import.